# Can parathread produce blocks?

Tags: parachain, rococo, parathread

I followed the [Cumulus tutorials](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/cumulus/rococo/) and registered a parathread in Rococo chain but my chain doesn't produce any block. As far as I know, parathread functions the same as a parachain you have to bid for the right to write to a block for every block. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Parathreads protocol is still under development. So no, currently parathreads do not create blocks, but this is on the immediate roadmap, and when it happens, there will be some economics around when a parathread will be able to produce a block, for example, bidding higher than other parathreads using the DOT token to produce a block at a certain point in time.

Answer (score 0):

`parathred` can not produce a block`(best block)` .
You can test it simply by cloning a parachain node template and polkadot code and then make a private network and connect your parachain into relay chain and then you will see there that parathred is not able to produce best block that `best block`  is block prodution.
If you want to know how to make private network and connect parachain into relay chain then reply in the same comment.